# Multiple SQL managed Instances in Same subnet

Tags: sql, azure, instance, managed, subnet

I need to create 2 Azure SQL Managed instances in same subnet. But when I create the first SQL Managed instance, it locks the subnet and I'm unable to create other managed instance in the same subnet. Has anyone experienced this issue and know what needs to be done here.

We have data which is more then 8TB hence need to have atleast 2 SQL Managed instances.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue - did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The opening of the article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/vnet-existing-add-subnet) implies that multiple managed instances can reside in the same subnet, but other documentation seems to indicate that may not be the case. Certainly, once a subnet has been delegated to SQL Managed Instance, only that resource type is allowed.

In either case, the network latency within a subnet should be the same as latency between subnets in the same VNET (or even VNETs in the same region). Could you create a second subnet for the new MI?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Matthew. I want to avoid creating multiple subnets if I don't have to. Is there any ARM Template available for deploying multiple SQL MI's in same subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the calculations and examples provided in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/vnet-subnet-determine-size?view=azuresql#multi-instance-subnets) documentation, it should be possible to deploy multiple Managed Instances of different tiers to the same subnet, provided there is enough space within the subnet.

Edit:
I've done some testing and can confirm that it is possible to have multiple MIs on the same subset.